# AttributeError: module '...' has no attribute '...'

Tags: python, python-import

I have the files:

**biomes.py**

```
import animals

...

class woodsBiome(baseBiome):
    # I do stuff
    def __init__(self):
        self.animals = animals.generateAnimals(5)
```

**animals.py**

```
def generateAnimals(quantity):
    # I do stuff
```

When I run `__init__` on `biomes.woodsBiome`, it fails at `animals.generateAnimals(5)`. It gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "game.py", line 10, in <module>
    import animals
  File "/path/to/files/animals.py", line 4, in <module>
    from game import die
  File "/path/to/files/game.py", line 22, in <module>
    areaMap = biomes.generateMap(xMax, yMax)
  File "/path/to/files/biomes.py", line 85, in generateMap
    biomeList = [woodsBiome(), desertBiome(), fieldBiome()]
  File "path/to/files/biomes.py", line 41, in __init__
    self.animals = animals.generateAnimals(5)
AttributeError: module 'animals' has no attribute 'generateAnimals'
```

I have a feeling there's something obvious I'm missing. Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a circular import problem.

Comment: This could be a few different things. Are you running this in something like Anaconda or Canopy?

Comment: Yeah.  Does `animals.py` also import `biomes`?

Comment: Can you actually include the full traceback and remove the `...` please?

Comment: @JohnGordon @user2357112 `animals.py` does not import `biomes`, but it does import one function from a module that imports both `biomes` and `animals`.

Comment: @roganjosh Done.

Comment: So `animals.py` does (indirectly) import `biomes`.  You can't do that.  Reorganize your code so that your modules are arranged in "layers", and each layer only imports from layers below itself.

Comment: But I'm not importing `biomes`, I'm importing a function from `biomes`, doesn't that make it non-circular?

Comment: `biomes` imports `animals`, as shown in your code example.  You also commented that `animals` imports another module which itself imports `biomes`.  That's circular.  (It doesn't matter that you're only importing a single function.)

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite comment yet, so here's a queston.

In the code there, I noticed that your class calls 
`__init__()`
 without self in it. Is this how it is in your code? Does calling the class as

`__init__(self)`

change anything?

Comment: No, it's just my mistake. Fixing that.